# Writing to file - Contents of the file aren't whats expected

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, io

Im writing an array to file. The writing to file is successful but it is not giving me the desired effect.
Im expecting something like this.

> F,Condor,240 kg,2
>
> A,Fish,2 kg,4
>
> T,Bear,300 kg,4

But I get this:

> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302
>
> [LAnimals;@55f96302 ~ ~ ~

I have a feeling this is because it is being written in binary or something similar. Here is my write submodule.

```
public void writeAquatic() throws IOException                                                                
{                                                                                                            
    BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;                                                                      
    String fileName = "Output.txt";                                                                          
    outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));                                             
    for(int p = 0; p < animals.length; p++)                                                                  
    {                                                                                                        
        outputWriter.write(animals.toString());                                                                      
        outputWriter.newLine();                                                                              
    }                                                                                                        
    outputWriter.flush();                                                                                    
    outputWriter.close();                                                                                    
}
```

Background Info - The array is an array of Objects, 3 objects make up the array - Flying Object, Terrestrial Object and Aquatic Object. Each represents a type of animal and contains info relating to each. Aka Species,Mass and numlegs/fins/wings.

Any help is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 1):

try

```
outputWriter.write(animals[p].toString());
```

instead of

```
outputWriter.write(animals.toString());
```